# Using appropriate layout markup according to screen resolution

Tags: android

I've got a design list for 480x800, 1024x600, 1280x800. How do I ask android to use exact markup based on user screen's resolution ? 
As far as I know there're only abstract means(hdpi,xdpi) for solving resolution difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I ask android to use exact markup based on user screen's resolution ?

Talented developers don't do that. Talented developers realize that only a percentage of Android devices run at the resolutions listed above, just as desktop Web browsers do not run at only three window sizes. Talented developers work with the graphics designer to come up with fluid layouts for different screen sizes (e.g., `-normal`, `-large`, `-xlarge`), which may or may not run at the aforementioned resolutions. For example, there are devices with screen sizes ranging from 4" to 7" that run at 800x480, and there are devices with screen sizes from 4.5" to 10.1" running at 1280x800 (or thereabouts).

> As far as I know there're only abstract means(hdpi,xdpi) for solving resolution difference.

`-hdpi` and `-xhdpi` have nothing to do with screen resolution. They are for screen density. Density is independent of resolution, and density is largely independent of size.

Comment: yeah, I know it, but my question is "How do I recognize density and use  on of the three markups ?"

Comment: @user971155: Things that should vary by density (e.g., icons), you use `-ldpi`, `-mdpi`, `-hdpi`, and `-xhdpi` resource set qualifiers (e.g., `res/drawable-xhdpi/`. Things that should vary by screen size (e.g., layouts), you use `-small`, `-normal`, `-large`, and `-xlarge` resource set qualifiers (e.g., `res/layout-xlarge/`), optionally mixing in `-land` for landscape orientations (e.g., `res/layout-xlarge-land/`). Or, for Android 3.2+, you can define your own buckets for size in dips, using `-wNNNdp`, `-hNNNdp`, and kin. See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Uhm, but what if I don't build against 3.2 ? In my case I have to specify layout according to resolution, which is density related - so I need to somehow use one markup with small dpi, medium - with medium, etc

Comment: @user971155: "I have to specify layout according to resolution" -- no, you do not. Please re-read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create folder based screen width or height. For example

res/layout-w480dp, res/layout-w1024dp, res/layout-w1280dp

Or

res/layout-h800dp, res/layout-h600dp

Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), Table 2. Configuration qualifier names.

Comment: Note that those are only available on Android 3.2+, and note that they do not address the question, as they are tied to dip values, not px values ("resolution").

Comment: Yes, you are right. As far as I know all the developer documentation is on dp not pixel. I may be misunderstand your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, you can markup the layout folder by   that is the minimum required screen resolution for the layout you can set one to min600 and one to min 800.

I think this markup scheme is supported in honeycomb and above and since these are tablets resolutions, they will have either anyway.

see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)